# Spring Data JPA findAll where a Set contains a Set

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find a way to findAll where a certain field (MySQL `Set` of numbers) contains an item or a set of items. I see there is a `contains` keyword but I'm not sure if this applies to Sets.

I was thinking something like this:

```
public interface IScheduleRepository extends Repository<Schedule, Long> {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    List<Schedule> findAllByDaysOfTheWeekContains(Set<Long> days);
}
```

and within the schedule class:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Long> daysOfTheWeek;
```

Does Spring Data JPA support checking if sets contain an item? Or further, if sets contain a set?

Comment: JPA expects a property of an Entity, like findAllByFirstNameIn( List<String> names);
 make sure what column name you want to use while querying data. if daysOfTheWeek is a property then user findAllByDaysOfTheWeekIn(Set<Long> days)

Comment: @krishnathota Yes that is all there. daysOfTheWeek is stored as a Set of numbers and I want to retrieve rows where a given number (or set of numbers) is in that set. Is the `In` keyword able to do that set membership?

Comment: yes, In should do that for you. please try and let me know if doesn't work.

Comment: @krishnathota That does not work. I think that Sets can only store strings. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to set the default for the set and inserting values for the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<Schedule> findAllByDaysOfTheWeekIn(Set<Long> days);` should be working fine, if the `daysOfTheWeek` is an Entity attribute(column). please refer the [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more details. under query creation you can see the combinations.